# Handling validations of required fields of a map inside a list in Moqui

Tags: moqui

For adding validations for the mandatory fields for a service being developed for a REST API, I am able to use the “required” attribute which validates the fields when set to true. This worked as expected for parameters marked with required=”true”, in a map.

However, for the use-case where I have a list, say, I want my service to take items **list** as input and would like to validate some required fields for each item, it does not automatically validate the fields with required="true".

I am able to handle this by adding extra logic in the code, but wanted to check if there is a recommended way for this or if anything is missed here which can automatically handle such validations in Moqui?

Example service definition:

```
<service verb="create" noun="Example">
   <in-parameters>
       <parameter name="user" type="Map" required="true">
           <parameter name="firstName" required="true"/>
           <parameter name="lastName" required="true"/>
       </parameter>
       <!-- Below list does not validate required fields -->
       <parameter name="items" type="List" required="true">
           <parameter name="itemMap" type="Map" required="true">
               <parameter name="name" required="true"/>
               <parameter name="description"/>
           </parameter>
       </parameter>
   </in-parameters>
   <actions>
      ...
   </actions>
</service>
```